Image Upload Feature on Marketing Cloud Landing Page Not Storing in Data Extension
I'm working on a project in Salesforce Marketing Cloud and need to create a landing page with an image upload feature. I have already set up a Data Extension named "ImageUploads" with the following fields: ImageBase64, CreatedDate, Id (primary key), and PostText.
I've written a Cloud Page script to handle the image upload, but the uploaded image is not being stored in the Data Extension as expected. Here is a simplified version of my script:
%%[
    var @ImageBase64, @PostText, @CreatedDate, @Id
    set @ImageBase64 = RequestParameter("ImageBase64")
    set @PostText = RequestParameter("PostText")
    set @CreatedDate = Now()
    set @Id = GUID()    
    if not empty(@ImageBase64) then
        InsertData("ImageUploads", "Id", @Id, "ImageBase64", @ImageBase64, "PostText", @PostText, "CreatedDate", @CreatedDate)
    endif
]%%

Despite this, the data is not being inserted into the Data Extension. What might be causing this issue, and how can I ensure that the uploaded image is stored correctly?
Thank you for your help!

DE Field limits;
We cannot see the DE, so just indications:

you seem to handle empty checks

PK is fine if the field is text/ 36 chars (length of a guid)

CreatedDate is fine if the field is date

Check PostText, is it required and is the input always there, what is the maxlength, what is the data type, does it match input?

Check imageBase64; How long is your typical base64 string?
What is the maxlength of the field ImageBase64?
If you create the DE via UI, maxlength you can seet is 4000 chars, if you do it via api, no limit.


== debug by either:

Wrapping an SSJS try catch around the ampscript and see if it returns an error
AMPScript for loop and SSJS

if all else fails, leaving out 50% of (non required) fields, repeat; works? error is in the omitted fields; fails; error is in the fields still used



You can remove the max-length on a DE field in Email Studio, allowing more than 4000 characters to be added (this update is not possible in Contact Builder)

yeah, or that :)

Using HTML I have created a button to upload the image from my local system and trying to store the image url in a variable @ImageBase64. The issue is nothing is getting stored in @ ImageBase64. Its returning empty value. So, when the code checks if @ ImageBase64 is empty and not inserting any data as the @ ImageBase64 variable value is empty.
